# Error: Login error on Sandbox Coinbase Pro

Tags: coinbase-api

I am trying to connect to Sandbox Coinbase Pro to test the API but I get the error

"Whoops!

We are sorry for the inconvenience, an unexpected error occurred. Please try again and if the problem persists, hard refresh your browser.

Error ID: 8dae9537"

Does anyone know why am I getting this error?
My trading account works without any problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you provide the correct credential for the sandbox? The sandbox has its own credential separate from the real account.

Comment: Sure, indeed I am able to log in but I cannot use the account